Biggest semi circle in a square
How can one find the biggest semi circle with that can be inscribed in a square of side "a' and show that it is indeed the biggest? I know there is a same question like this on the platform but the answer there is too straightforward .It directly jumps onto an equation for sides of square as "$max(1 + \cos\theta, 1 + \sin\theta)$"  but how does he got there is not explained clearly. Also the link mentioned in that question is not opening,it's showing error.  So I want to know a clear answer.

where are the similar questions?

One argument is as follows: inscribe a circle in a square. If you try to dilate it from any position on the square, it can only dilate from a corner. Do so, producing a semicircle angled at $45$ to the square sides. Then, the question is, is there any possible larger semicircle that could possibly fit? I think you will see the remaining argument that no possible larger semicircle could fit.

Hey@CalvinKhor I have already said , this question is already on the platform but the answers there are not quite CLEAR. That' s why I posted it again here. I didn't understand how he solved it there. There is not need to CLOSE the question. I want a clear answer please

@VirenderBhardwaj: question closure can seem abrupt. What you would probably need to do to get this reopened is edit the post to say  how you do not understand the linked answer or how you want a distinct answer, in which case it is likely people will view that as a question that is answerable/worth answering and then certain people might vote to reopen.

@RobinSparrow but I think I have explained it in the question that the answer there is so direct. It directly jumps onto an equation and sets it to max.but how does he got there is not explained clearly. Also the links mentioned in that question is not opening,it's showing error

@RobinSparrow I have edited the question and have provided some more info. about it

@VirenderBhardwaj I DIDN'T vote to CLOSE the question. BUT as far as I can see you did not LINK to a related question on the platform. ps rest assured that I read your question before commenting

@CalvinKhor can u explain to me the most voted answer given to that question? I didn't understand how he did it.
